# Release DHCP lease on Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: server, dhcp

How can I send a DHCP release packet for an address acquired by netplan?
I have configured dhcp for IPv4 in the installer (/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml).
I've tried `dhclient -r -v <interface>`, but it didn't seem to work.
[The reaseon is that I can only get three DHCP leases from my ISP, and want to use it for something else now(rather than wait 2 days to expire)]

Comment: Since the association between your IP address and the timeout is kept on the DHCP **server**, you, on the client, cannot affect it. You can place a firewall on a cheap system, e.g. Raspberry Pi, between your ISP and your local network. The RPi will get ONE IP address from the ISP, and can act as a DHCP server for your LAN, and the RPi will do NAT (Network Address Translation).

Comment: To clarify I want to send DHCPRELEASE (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2131#section-3.1) "Client to server relinquishing network address and cancelling remaining lease.". Thanks for the suggestion of using NAT, and indeed I do use that for most hosts. OTOH it's nice to have some external IPs to isloate some hosts outside of my LAN and also not have to mess with port forwarding.